# Woocommerce - Change tax class when a field is empty in checkout

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to set Zero Rate class when a field is empty in the checkout, I tried with woocommerce_product_tax_class, but nothing happens.

```
function wc_diff_rate_for_user( $tax_class, $product ) {
    $checkout = WC()->checkout();
    $billing_ie = $checkout->get_value( 'billing_ie' );

    if ($billing_ie == '') {
        $tax_class = 'Zero Rate';
    }
    else {
        $tax_class = 'ICMS';
    }
    return $tax_class;
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: I've never used this function personally, but have you looked at: https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_AJAX.html#_update_order_review

Comment: Don't know if you still look for help, but..which hook are you using for this function? Is it run? Do the tax classes exist? Etc :)